# RegExp to find/replace newlines within double quotes, not affecting newlines outside double-quotes

Tags: php, regex, csv

I've got a CSV file which gives problems importing because of the fields containing new line characters. As CSV importers treat every newline as a new row, the newlines in the fields mess things up.

So I want to replace every newline **within** double quotes with `<br>` leaving the 'real' newlines outside double quotes untouched.

First step would be to be able to create a regexp to get the newlines within the text file.

```
(\n|\r)
```

But after this I get lost, because I can't find the xxx within this expression:

```
(")(xxx)(\n|\r)(xxx)(")
```

And a solution to let the 'real' newlines untouched.

**Concluding: How can I replace every newline within a field, enclosed by double quotes with a `<br>`**

I'm now using sublime text to test the regex but later it will be used in a php application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Search pattern:

```
("[^"\n]*)\r?\n(?!(([^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)
```

Replacement Pattern:

```
$1<br>
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/wL9sQ4/2)

Comment: Almost!!! When you have multiple lines the newline at the end will also be replaced: http://regex101.com/r/wL9sQ4/1

Comment: Oh my this seems to be working !! Now just figuring out _how_ it works :)

Comment: Glad to know it worked out. Just for more info on regex `(?!(([^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)` is a lookahead that says don't match if **there are even number of quotes** ahead of the match.

Comment: What if there are several newlines between quotes ? It works only when there is only one new line (

Comment: @FəqanÇələbizadə: Difficult to understand it from your comments. Feel free to post a question so that I can try to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

Could use [preg_replace_callback()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to match the quoted parts with an [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php):

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('~"[^"]+"~', function ($m) {
  return preg_replace('~\r?\n~', "<br>", $m[0]);
}, $str);
```

`$m[0]` corresponds to what's matching the whole pattern.

[Test at eval.in](https://eval.in/205344); [Regex FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075)

Comment: Is it possible to put this in one regex? The two separate regexs work perfect, but it would be very handy if it was only one regex

Comment: @stUrb see anubhava solution for one regex :) Chose this one as it's simple.

Comment: @stUrb Oooh, somehow I thought the quotes should be removed :) Then it's even simpler, don't need capture group, see updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

CSV format is complicated and, in the general case, cannot be parsed reliably with regular expressions. My suggestion is to use a parser, for example, [parsecsv-for-php](https://github.com/parsecsv/parsecsv-for-php) handles quoted newlines quite decently:

```
$str = <<<EOF
42,okay,"okay too","here
be
""dragons""!",43

EOF;

$csv = new parseCSV();
$csv->heading = false;
$result = $csv->parse_string($str);
```

result:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "42"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "okay"
    [2]=>
    string(8) "okay too"
    [3]=>
    string(18) "here
be
"dragons"!"
    [4]=>
    string(2) "43"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm that's an interesting library! I definitely am going to look into using this library!

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue when importing a csv file using html5 drag and drop. I used below (javascript) fix and it is worked for me.

```
//Fix: if there are any line breaks in between column values, then that column value will be wrapped in double quotes
//first get all the double quoted values list using regex
var lineBreakList = textcontent.match(/(["'])(\\?)[\s\S]*?\1/g);
//search for line breaks using regex, if found replace it with empty value
lineBreakList.forEach(function (item) {
    textcontent = textcontent.replace(item, item.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, ''));
});
```

Hope this will help someone :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

  $line = "\"abc\",\"\n\",\"def\"\n";
  $line = preg_replace('/"(.*?)\\n(.*?)"/', "\"$1<br>$2\"", $line);

?>
```

With this input:

```
"abc","\n","def"\n
```

it prints this output:

```
"abc","<br>","def"\n
```

Comment: If the input is this: `"abc","def \n ghi","klm"\n` The regexp won't replace it.

Comment: Changed a bit the regexp to address your comment (I didn't test it yet, but it should work...)